# How to package nodejs and install a windows service with NSIS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, nsis

I am currently using [os-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-service) to create a Windows service that needs to be packaged with my Electron application. Currently, everything is installed with NSIS, but I'm not quite sure how to install and run an [os-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-service) script during installation. Likewise for uninstallation.

Anyone with experience with this? The service is installed using node to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Node.js runtime on target computer it *should* contain everything necessary to run apps properly.

Node.js also installs **npm** so it *should be* possible to execute `npm install os-service` from your NSIS installer somehow like this:

1. Install Node.js runtime from your installer (it is .msi package so
   use ExecWait command to run it from some Temp folder)
2. Get the npm **path**. Here I suppose npm on
   Windows is something like npm.exe located in bin or similar
   directory of Node.js and the path can be retrieved from Registry.
3. Run the npm: `npm install os-service` from your installer - again use ExecWait or related. You will have to use absolute paths and so on.

I have no experience with web apps, there more be some dependencies and so on so you need to do a little more investigation.